# Comparing several values (rows) in a column (numeric) with multiple conditions r

Tags: r, for-loop, compare

As a beginner in R I am having trouble deriving specific data from my dataframe. My data has measurements every 10 mins, which is 144 rows on a daily basis. What I want to do is compare 3 values (rows) within the 'batteryAvailable' and 'date' column that meet certain conditions:

- the values of batteryAvailable of the 2 outer rows have to be equal
- the difference in batteryAvailable between the middle row and the 2 outer rows has to be at least 5
- the max. allowed interval is one day (so difference in date of the first and last row has to be <= 24h)

The batteryAvailable column represents a percentage, in the df it is a numeric value ranging from [0-100]

Example of the data:

```
          date         batteryAvailable solarChargeTotal    V2GTotal

1   05/05/2014 07:30        61               389.7           354.4
2   05/05/2014 07:40        61               389.7           354.4
3   05/05/2014 07:50        62               389.8           354.4
4   05/05/2014 08:00        62               389.8           354.4
5   05/05/2014 08:10        63               389.9           354.4
6   05/05/2014 08:20        63               389.9           354.4
7   05/05/2014 08:30        64               390             354.4
8   05/05/2014 08:40        65               390             354.4
9   05/05/2014 08:50        64               390.1           354.5
10  05/05/2014 09:00        64               390.1           354.5
11  05/05/2014 09:10        62               390.1           354.7
12  05/05/2014 09:20        62               390.2           354.8
13  05/05/2014 09:30        64               390.4           354.8
14  05/05/2014 09:40        66               390.5           354.8
15  05/05/2014 09:50        68               390.7           354.8
16  05/05/2014 10:00        71               390.9           354.8
17  05/05/2014 10:10        72               391             354.8
18  05/05/2014 10:20        72               391             354.9
19  05/05/2014 10:30        74               391.2           354.9
20  05/05/2014 10:40        77               391.4           354.9
```

If the above conditions are met, a calculation follows. So far I have tryed using a 'for loop' to do this. However it is extremely innefficient and I am not getting all possible output. This is what my code looks like now:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) {


h <- i-1
j <- i+1

rowh <- df[h,]
rowi <- df[i,]
rowj <- df[j,]

## all the conditions
if (!is.na(rowh$batteryAvailable) &
    !is.na(rowi$batteryAvailable)  &
    !is.na(rowj$batteryAvailable) &
    rowh$batteryAvailable == rowj$batteryAvailable & 
    rowh$batteryAvailable != rowi$batteryAvailable  &
    abs(rowh$batteryAvailable - rowi$batteryAvailable) > 5 &
    difftime(rowj$date, rowh$date, units = "hours") < 24)  {

## the calculation
Charge_h <- (rowi$solarChargeTotal-rowh$solarChargeTotal) 
V2G_h <- (rowi$V2GTotal-rowh$V2GTotal) 

Charge_j <- (rowj$solarChargeTotal-rowi$solarChargeTotal) 
V2G_j <- (rowj$V2GTotal-rowi$V2GTotal) 


if (!exists("bat_efficiency")){
  bat_efficiency <- data.frame()
} 

## storage of found values
if (exists("bat_efficiency")){
  rowj$Charge <- Charge_h + Charge_j
  rowj$V2G <- V2G_h + V2G_j
  bat_efficiency <-rbind(bat_efficiency, rowj)
    }
  }
}
```

The condition for the difference of at least 5 between outer and middle row results in no found points. This is odd as I know they are there. Leaving this condition out gets me only observations where the battery difference is 1 or 2.

Basically what I want is a way to use the concept of 3 variables (e.g. h, i, j) moving through rows to compare values within a timespan of max. 1 day, without using a for loop. And maybe someone knows what is  happening with the condition of => 5, I dont get an error message, there is just no output.

Note: On one day there could be more than one occasion where the requirements are met, I am interested in all of them. Not that it stops after the first found value.